# How to stabilize a bar table with hairpin legs

Tags: wood, technique, furniture, design, glue

I'm doing a one-off project for a much-needed small dining space in the holiday home.

I have a set of 4 hairpin legs at 106cm each that I want to use for a bar table. I want a nice table top but want to keep it under AUS$100 if possible, whilst ensuring stability.

Have seen finished/stained acacia panels at Bunnings that are the perfect length/depth (1800 x 600) for what we need, but are only 18mm thick.

Any recommendations on how I can combine the 2 for a sturdy bar/dining table/kitchen island?

I was going to buy 2 panels, sand one side of each down, wood glue and nail together. Then attach the legs and add a centre leg for a support piece.

Yes? No? Rookie-error alert?  Lol

Open to suggestions as I am NOT a woodworker by any stretch - just a pregnant woman wanting to get it done, give it a crack and take one thing off hubby's to-do list (I have teenage hands to help with lifting).

Comment: Bar table/breakfast bar is more accurate.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Have you considered that maybe hairpin legs aren't the ideal candidate for this? As for the top, 18mm in any decent hardwood (and some softwoods!) is perfectly adequate for a medium-sized table, even one likely to see more use than this, if the legs/leg structure is suitable and attached properly.

Comment: To expand upon the @Graphus comment, 18mm cannot span the overall size of the table without sagging.  Many tables have tops this thickness, but supported by aprons between the legs.  You need to be able to connect aprons to the legs to carry the top properly.

Comment: @Ashlar, ??? There's basically no potential for sag here, even in pine 18mm should be perfectly capable of spanning the width without sagging to any degree in service. It's the inherent wobbliness of tall hairpin legs (and their unknown attachment to the tabletop) that would concern me.

Comment: Sounds Cool! Let me know how it works out

Comment: @Graphus We are talking about a 18mm (3/4") table spanning 1800mm (6 feet) of length as well. I believe that needs some support regardless of  wood grain direction.

Comment: @Ashlar, as with almost any table I'm assuming the legs won't be right at the two ends (and in from both front and back edges FWIW) rather than being mounted directly at the four corners. With the style of hairpin legs I'm visualising ....we could really do with some pics to go on here..... they're always well in from the corners. Additionally this is a table in a holiday home, not a shelf for heavy pots & pans or books, so no sustained loads (other than the weight of the material itself) is a reasonable usage assumption. But for peace of mind let's go absolute worst-case scenario here [contd]

Comment: ...and assume the full unsupported span. The Sagulator doesn't have data for acacia as you might already have seen, but substitute any pine you care to (again, aiming for worst possible case example) and assume far more than a minimal central weight (I went with 50lbs!) and sag is *still* classed as Acceptable, at barely more than 1mm. To try to get a read on what the sag might actually be, if you're unfamiliar with acacia it's stiffer than birch, Doug fir and even white oak. Its stiffness is actually just barely under that of jatoba, AKA Brazilian cherry.

Comment: Hi guys,  Thanks for the warm welcome.  Yes, have considered that hairpin legs may not be suitable for this size breakfast bar.  They're just what I have on hand so was hoping to use them for this little project rather than going and spending more cash and having them sit around.    So, just wondering what my best options are -  Add bracing to the bottom and a centre leg/s of somesort in order to utilise the legs? Cut down on the size?  Try sell them off completely and spend the extra to buy a ready made breakfast bar + barstools?

Comment: Am I able to share a pic to this forum or no?  I have a pic of exactly what I have in my head.  